# what does it mean by saying that union members can only be manipulted one at a time?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, unions

I was just reading up on the theory behind unions and stacks. The book (Object Orientated Programming with C++ by E Balagurusamy) said that "members of a union can only be manipulated one at a time". But I was messing around with unions. I did this with no error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "ConsoleApplication1.h"

using namespace std;
//user defined data types
#define writeln(x)(cout<<x<<endl)
union result
{
    int marks;
    char grade;
    float percent;
};
int main()
{  
    result result;
    result.marks = 90;
    result.grade = 'a';
    writeln(result.grade);
    writeln(result.marks);
}
```

So may you please clarify what that statement meant. Thanks:).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior

Comment: In short, some compilers allow you to do this (mainly because it is legal in C) but the C++ standard explicitly makes it Undefined Behavior to read from a different union member than the one that was last written to ("is active").

Comment: In C++, that you can do something does not mean that it's valid or permitted. You *can* drive 100 mph through a school zone, but you will not convince any judge that it means that you did nothing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that you are invoking Undefined Behaviour. Let us see what happen of each line of code:

```
result result;         // ok, you have declared an union
result.marks = 90;     // ok, result.marks is defined
result.grade = 'a';    // ok, result.grade is defined, but result.mark is no longer
writeln(result.grade); // ok, access to the last written member of the union
writeln(result.marks); // UB: access to a member which is not the last writter
```

UB is really unfriendly for newcomers, because anything can happen:

- the compiler could detect the problem and raise a warning or error (but it is not required to...)
- `writeln(result.marks)` could write `90` or the code of the `'a'`character  (`97`) or nothing, or something else of even end the program

And as anything can happen, you can get the expected behaviour on one run, and later get a different one.

Long story made short: do not play with that...

Comment: ...or the compiler explicitly allows for it. But that's not a portable assumption.

Answer (score 1):

- result result;
- result.marks = 90;

  // wite 4 byte start from &result(memory : 5a 00 00 00 - 90)
  **NOTE:** memory used mechanism [big endian or little endian](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html) 90 is 00 00 00 5a, big endian memory will 5a 00 00 00 and little endian will opposite
  [image: memory when assign marks]
- result.grade = 'a';

  // wite 1 byte start from &result (memory : 61 - 'a')
  [image: memory when assign grade]
- writeln(result.grade); // get 1 byte start at &result
- writeln(result.marks); // get 4 byte start at &result

Comment: This is a nice and detailed answer. Simply it ignores the fact that the compiler is not required to access the memory. Per the *strict aliasing rule* the compiler is allowed to expect that `result.marks` has not been changed, so it could keep the `90` value in a register and use it with no memory access. That is the reason why UB must be avoided, even if a specific run on a specific platform gives the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In a `union` every variable shares the same memory. For that reason you get the outputs 'a' and '97'.

```
result result;
result.marks = 90; // memory value is 90
result.grade = 'a'; // memory value is 97 ('a')
writeln(result.grade); // print 97 ('a')
writeln(result.marks); // print 97
```

Comment: what about most likely `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`?

Comment: @user3365922 You are right. As the post linked by Max Langhof states it is undefined behaviour. I just wanted to clarify what union does.